# Is it possible to disable oracle trigger on Oracle Unit Test startup

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have a table that has a trigger used to write the row to a different database, that we don't want to execute during out unit tests. Is there a way to disable and reenable the trigger during startup and tear down?

In the start up I have tried

```
BEGIN 
    ALTER TRIGGER CAMMS_DATA.TR_CO_DTL_AI DISABLE; 
END;
```

and get the error

```
Startup User PL/Sql Code (1/4) failed: ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:
```

Comment: You can't run DDL inside an anonymous block. Try without the begind and end statements, or if you must do it that way, use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL's can be executed only with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

```
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CAMMS_DATA.TR_CO_DTL_AI DISABLE';
END;
```

But be aware that DDL also means automatic `COMMIT`

Comment: trying this I get a pls-00101 Encountered the symbol end error. If I put a ; at the end of it then I get ora-00933 command not properly ended